# How to replace content using AJAX

Tags: node.js, ajax, pug

Currently coding a project where upon loading will replace a gif on the page with a numbered list after the AJAX finishes. I cant find anything about how to do this, and what i should put in my app.get. I know i'll have to use load but AJAX is completely new to me and i don't understand a lick of it.

My node.js server code

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express'),
    request = require('request'),
    app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

});

const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(`Started server on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

The pug template i'm using

```
doctype
html
    head
        title PokeyManz
        h1 Top ten starter Pokemon!
    body
        p1 For many gamers, this decision was one of the most influential choices they've ever made!
        div(id='div1')
            img(src='/img/pokeball_gif.gif')
```

What i currently have in my ajax file

```
'use strict';

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'localhost:3000/');

xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('load');

});
```

Comment: You can pass the image address to your pug template, then replace the content to use it.

Comment: The image address is already in the pug template; i hope im not misunderstanding you

Comment: Jummm, I thought you were trying to pass the image from the server to the template, then, are you trying to do something like a loader, waiting for the AJAX call to be completed?

Comment: Yes, what im trying to do is load the page with the gif, and when the ajax call is completed, the ajax removes the gif and replaces it with a numbered list (in this case the numbered list would be the top 10 starter pokemon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to simplify a little I would encourage you to use a library with support for AJAX calls, [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) will do the job just fine. So, look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sigfriedCub1990/d49kpvqx/12/) it's using `jQuery.ajax()` method to get the list of 10 pokemons, of course you can replace the Pokemon image from the init with an spinner or the gif you post about. Hope this helps you. Cheers, sigfried